# Showing a specific projection has a regular value

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be open sets, both containing the origin.  Also let $W=\{\mathbf{x}\in U\mid x_n=0\}$. Suppose that $f:U\rightarrow V$ is a smooth submersion, and that $f_{\mid W}$ is also a smooth submersion. Finally, let $S=f^{-1}(\mathbf{0})$.

If $\pi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the projection $\pi(\mathbf{x})=x_n$, I want to show $0$ is a regular value of $\pi$.

The hint I'm given is to consider the tangent spaces of $S$ and $W$.

So I suppose the contrary,  that for some $q\in S\cap W$, $d\pi_q$ is the zero map. This means $TS_q\subset\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n-1}}\}$. I also know that $TW_q\subset\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{n-1}}\}$. What I don't see is how to combine this to show $f_{\mid W}$ is not a submersion at $q$ (which I'm guessing is the right approach).

What am I missing? For context, this problem is from an intro to smooth manifolds problem set, so I don't know any fancy techniques.  In other words, I want to keep this as low-tech as possible.

Comment: I'm not convinced that argument by contradiction is the best approach here. What I suggest you do before picking a logical approach is to first write out the commutative diagram of all tangent spaces and derivative maps that are involved, which reduces your problem to pure linear algebra (what could be more "low-tech"?). For example I see five relevant tangent spaces, namely $T_q U$, $T_q W$, $T_q S$, $T_{f(q)} V$, $T_{\pi(q)} \mathbb{R}$. One other thing: bases are irrelevant. This is about ranks of vector subspaces and equations amongst those ranks that arise from theorems of linear algebra.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Can you take a look at my answer, see if I used your hints correctly? And also thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works, based on what Lee Mosher said above.

We have a surjective map $df_q: TU_q\rightarrow TV_{f(q)}$, and the kernel is $TS_q$, which is then dimension $n-m$. We also have a map $d\pi_q:TU_q\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}_{\pi(q)}$, and the kernel is $TW_q$, of dimension $n-1$.

Because $f$ is a submersion when restricted to $W$, we also have $df_q: TW_q\rightarrow TV_{f(q)}$  is surjective, and the kernel is $TS_q\cap TW_q$, of dimension $n-1-m$.  This means $TS_q\not\subset TW_q=\ker(d\pi_q)$, so $d\pi_q:TS_q\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}_{\pi(q)}$ is surjective.

This means $0$ is actually a regular value of $\pi_{\mid S}$.